Pandas to find a streak of sales but with a tolerance for streak interruption
I am trying to use Panda's to filter out a DataFrame to find a streak of sales that shall be of variant length. I am looking to identify periods of consecutive sales, but also allow for some days with no sale in between. In the df below, I am looking to select rows 12 to 19.
data = [['2023-11-16', 1], ['2023-11-17', 0], ['2023-11-20', 1], 
['2023-11-21', 0], ['2023-11-22', 1], ['2023-11-24', 0], 
['2023-11-27', 0], ['2023-11-28', 0], ['2023-11-29', 0], 
['2023-11-30', 0], ['2023-12-01', 0], ['2023-12-04', 0],
['2023-12-05', 1], ['2023-12-06', 1] , ['2023-12-07', 1],
['2023-12-08', 1], ['2023-12-11', 0], ['2023-12-12', 0],
['2023-12-13', 1], ['2023-12-14', 1], ['2023-12-15', 0], 
['2023-12-18', 0],  ['2023-12-19', 0], ['2023-12-20', 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'sold'])



How many days of no sales are allowed in a streak?

Ideally it shall be a percentage of past consecutive days, if I am selling for 20 days in a row I can accept 3 no sales but if I'm selling for 4 and then 3 days in a row have no sales then it cannot be a streak

Here is a customisable algorithm that should help with your use case:
def find_streaks(df: pd.DataFrame, allowed_no_sales = 2, minimum_streak = 4):
    streaks: list[int, int] = []

    start = 0
    end = 0
    current_sales = 0
    current_no_sales = 0
    for current in range(len(df)):
        if df['sold'][current] == 0:
            current_no_sales += 1
            if current_no_sales > allowed_no_sales:
                if current_sales >= minimum_streak:
                    streaks.append([start, end])
                current_sales = 0
                start = -1
        else:
            end = current
            current_no_sales = 0
            current_sales += 1
            if start == -1:
                start = current

    if current_sales >= minimum_streak:
        streaks.append([start, end])

    return streaks

allowed_no_sales is the amount of consecutive no sale days that are allowed (those no sales days could appear multiple time in a sequence, for example: 1 0 0 0 [1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1] 0 0 0 1, the captured sequence is in between brackets for allowed_no_sales = 2.
minimum_streak is the minimum amount of days with sales that should appear in the sequence. For example 1 0 1 0 1  at the start of your DataFrame would not be a streak for minimum_streak = 4.
For your DataFrame:
import pandas as pd

data = [['2023-11-16', 1], ['2023-11-17', 0], ['2023-11-20', 1], 
['2023-11-21', 0], ['2023-11-22', 1], ['2023-11-24', 0], 
['2023-11-27', 0], ['2023-11-28', 0], ['2023-11-29', 0], 
['2023-11-30', 0], ['2023-12-01', 0], ['2023-12-04', 0],
['2023-12-05', 1], ['2023-12-06', 1] , ['2023-12-07', 1],
['2023-12-08', 1], ['2023-12-11', 0], ['2023-12-12', 0],
['2023-12-13', 1], ['2023-12-14', 1], ['2023-12-15', 0], 
['2023-12-18', 0],  ['2023-12-19', 0], ['2023-12-20', 0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'sold'])

print(find_streaks(df))

Returns [[12, 19]], the streak you identified.

Thank you Ivan, isn't a bad idea to iterate over entire datasets?

@cksrc If you have a very large dataset, it may not be desirable to iterate over it using a loop in Python as it is a very inefficient process. You may want to use another language.
Ideally we would want to use a vector operation, but in your case it isn't possible as the streaks depend on surrounding data which can only be run through via an iteration with an internal context. You could use a rolling window approach to identify the end of streaks, but it would be equivalent to iteration.
Other than that, it is perfectly fine to use iteration over datasets :)
